# Anaconda3-4.3.1 installation on Linux - Spyder won't launch (PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets)

Tags: linux, pyqt5, spyder

I just installed the above mentioned Anaconda version. `Jupyter` works fine, but I can't launch `Spyder` as I get

```
 File "/proj/mianxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/proj/mianxx/anaconda3/bin//spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/proj/mianxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/proj/mianxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/proj/mianxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /proj/mianxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../././libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_mutex_init
```

I am too much of a noob to take it from here...Any hints?

I've checked [This GIT entry](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3383) but I can't make much of it. It also seems old, despite being open.

**EDIT**

The issue appears to be related to `tcsh`, which is the default `shell` called.
If one issues

```
bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder
```

This works and launches `spyder` correctly. However,

```
bash
spyder
```

will generate the same error as above.
Thanks to @Carlos Cordoba for his help.

Comment: Please reinstall Anaconda. By installing the `pyqt5` wheel with `pip install pyqt5` you (most probably) broke your installation. That's because Anaconda comes with its own `pyqt` package that is incompatible with `pyqt5`. Then try to start Spdyer again

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should say that I am only a user and I have no admin privileges of any sort.  I can't `pip` either as I do not have internet access on these machines.
So if I understand your comment, I should wipe the current installation and re-try?
Will do and report.

Comment: Done. Same result as before.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was mistaken in my first comment. What version of Linux are you using?

Comment: `uname -r` gives:
2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: It looks like Centos 6, which should be fine. Unfortunately some googling didn't help, other than saying that this could be caused by an old Glib version. But Anaconda comes with a very recent Glib (2.50.2). So I'm sorry, but I can't help you anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused here. Are we saying this is a Spyder problem? Or is it a Linux problem? Perhaps are we saying that we don't have a clue and I need to dig further? I'm asking because if it is a Spyder issue I will report it on GitHub.

Comment: I'm the Spyder maintainer and I can tell you this is not a Spyder problem. It's a Qt5 problem. Unfortunately, I haven't seen this error before and Google was of no help to understand what could be causing it.

Comment: You mean to say that Qt is somehow flawed? What do you think would be a sensible next move, to try to understand this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's flawed. I think your system is missing a library that makes it fail. Do you have an special value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns a very long string, lots of stuff specific to my company I suspect.
Nothing pointing to anything Qt though. Do you think I could search for the location of these libs and add the path to a variable? Maybe `path`? Or does it need to be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I have looked in the /usr/lib tree and I can see `Qt3` and `Qt4`, but no `Qt5`, so maybe it's just not there. I will ask my Linux guys and see.

Comment: Anaconda comes with its own version of Qt5, don't worry about it. What if you start Spyder like this: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder`?

Comment: I don't know this syntax.
If I copy your grayed command verbatim, I get `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=: command not found`

Comment: Just paste it as it is. Instead of running `spyder` in a terminal, please run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder`

Comment: I did. As I wrote before, I get the following reply:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=: Command not found.`
Maybe I should mention this is a `tcsh`?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Please use bash and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139198/discussion-between-mike-anblips-and-carlos-cordoba).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Carlos Cordoba's help, When I try to use:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder
```

in terminal, it really works but '**spyder**' can't. Then I use:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

to open bashrc, write

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

save and open terminal with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

retry enter:

```
spyder
```

in terminal, works!

---

**UPDATE**

There is still something wrong when I write `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder` in bashrc, every time when I open terminal, there is an error shows that **space** shouldn't write before **spyder**, but when I alter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder` into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=spyder`, Spyder won't launch again, So there are two ways can solve this problem:

1. Don't mind see warning every time you open terminal
2. Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder` open spyder

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer (work with **Ubuntu 18.04**)

Check the version of `pyqt` 
conda list `pyqt` 
if it is **5.6.x**

It won't work so I resorted to this simple command:

```
conda install pyqt=5.9.2
```

(and later also to
`qt=5.9.5 qtpy=1.4.1`   check all with conda list qt)

then you're good to launch spyder

Answer (score 0):

More info on lixun's answer. In fact you may do

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
$ spyder
```

and it will work without any warning. Seasoned spyder/qt/anaconda specialists may be able to explain why. I do not feel this is a good solution. It is just a workaround.

I am using anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04.